# For loop in Javascript isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

New to javascript, but in my mind my html should produce a grid that I created. None of the tr or td elements are being populated from my js file. Does anyone know why or what I'm missing? Thanks for your help.

Here is my js file:

```
function showGrid() {
    var gridDiv = document.getElementById("gridDiv");
    gridDiv.innerHTML = genGrid();
}

function genGrid() {
    var html = "";
    var row = 8;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var tdClass = "";

    for (i = row; i > 0; i--) {

        html += "<tr>";

        for (j = row; j > 0; j--) {
            var r = j % 2;
            if (r = 0) {
                tdClass = "red";
            } else {
                tdClass = "black";
            }

            html += "<td class=\"" + tdClass + "\"></td>";
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    return html;
}
```

Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type=text/css href="style.css">
        <script src="genGame.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="showGrid()">

        <div id="gridDiv">
        This should get overridden
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are missing data. There's nothing in your `td` elements. Hence there's nothing to show.

Comment: That depends on the CSS

Comment: If I had to guess, the OP probably has width, height, and background CSS that is not posted

Comment: You also have a typo. "if (r = 0) {" should be "if (r === 0) {" as you have it, it is assgning 0 to r, but tests like "if(0)" which is false so always will be black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
    <div id="gridDiv">
    This should get overridden
    </div>
```

Should be

```
    <table id="gridDiv">
    This should get overridden
    </table>
```

Comment: That's not the only problem. The problem is that there's nothing in the OP's table.

Comment: `html += "<td class=\"" + tdClass + "\"></td>";`

Comment: this made the table appear in the html, ty @Ed Heal.

Answer (score 0):

You have no data in `<td></td>`

```
<script>
    function showGrid() {
   var gridDiv = document.getElementById("gridDiv");
    gridDiv.innerHTML = genGrid();
}
    function genGrid() {
    var html = "";
    var row = 8;
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var tdClass = "";

    for (i = row; i > 0; i--) {

        html += "<tr>";

        for (j = row; j > 0; j--) {
            var r = j % 2;
            if (r == 0) {
                tdClass = "red";
            } else {
                tdClass = "black";
            }

            html += "<td class=\"" + tdClass + "\">-data-</td>";
        }
        html += "</tr>";
    }
    return html;
}
</script>



<body onload="showGrid()">
        <table id="gridDiv">
            This should get overridden
        </table>
 </body>
```

comparision should also ok

```
if (r == 0) {
                tdClass = "red";
            }
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/f3cz9r5b/)